# xslt select a node with transitive dependency

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

While converting xml to csv using xslt i am facing challenge dealing with transitive dependency.
Below is my xml (simplified):

```
<root>
    <hold id="H_100">
        <value1>A</value1>
    </hold>
    <hold id="H_200">
        <value1>B</value1>
    </hold>
    <hold id="H_300">
        <value1>C</value1>
    </hold>
    <party id="C_100">
        <value2>D</value2>
    </party>
    <party id="C_200">
        <value2>E</value2>
    </party>
    <party id="C_300">
        <value2>F</value2>
    </party>
    <party id="A_100">
        <value2>G</value2>
    </party>
    <party id="A_300">
        <value2>H</value2>
    </party>
    <relation hid="H100" pid="C_100"/>
    <relation hid="H100" pid="A_100"/>
    <relation hid="H200" pid="C_200"/> 
    <relation hid="H300" pid="A_300"/> 
</root>
```

And my expected output is (Party should be considered only when pid starts with A_) :

```
Hold,Party
A,G
B,
C,H
```

Does anyone know how to do this using xslt??

Comment: Are these `relation/@hid` values like `H100` referring to `hold/@id` values like `H_100`? Is the underscore missing in your posted snippet for the `hid` values or does that have to be added by the XSLT when trying to establish a cross-reference?

Comment: Yes underscore is missing in snippet. And yes they are related through relation element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XSLT 1.0 try as below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Hold', ',', 'Party', '&#xA;')"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="/root/*[name() = 'hold']">
        <xsl:variable name="var.hid" select="translate(@id, '_', '')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="var.pid" select="/root/relation[@hid = $var.hid and starts-with(@pid, 'A_')]/@pid"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(value1, ',', /root/party[@id = $var.pid]/value2, '&#xA;')"/>        
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And result will be as expected:

```
Hold,Party
A,G
B,
C,H
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow cross-references in XSLT you can use keys so with XSLT 2 or 3 you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:key name="rel" match="relation" use="@hid"/>
  <xsl:key name="party" match="party" use="@id"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:text>Hold,Party&#10;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="root/hold"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="hold">
      <xsl:value-of select="value1, key('party', key('rel', translate(@id, '_', ''))/@pid[starts-with(., 'A_')])/value2" separator=","/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbi

For XSLT 1 you can use the same keys but as `value-of` only outputs a single node you would need to split up the `value-of` used above into two to output the `value1` plus the referenced `value2`.

If in the real data the `hid` values have the underscore then you can simplify the subexpression `key('rel', translate(@id, '_', ''))` to `key('rel', @id)`, see http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbi/1. The above sample assumes the `hid` and `id` values differ and therefore tries to remove the underscore before using the key.